# Como inserir somente elementos que não existam?

Tags: mysql, python, sql-insert

Eu tenho um script em python que busca elementos de um banco e salva em outro, so que quando eu rodo o script ele está duplicando os dados.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `alarm` (`data`, `seconds`, `culprit`, `status`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
```

Tem algum modo que eu posso alterar esse INSERT para inserir somente o que não está contido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qual da chave primária da sua tabela "alarm"? Ela é que define se os seus registros estão duplicados. **Esta parte é essencial**. A partir daí, você pode fazer a inserção de várias maneiras:

1. INSERT IGNORE INTO ... : Ignora os registros duplicados (veja [aqui](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-ignore/))
2. INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE : Atualiza campos específicos se a chave for duplicada (veja [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))
3. REPLACE INTO ... : Se o registro estiver duplicado, apaga e insere a nova linha.

Comment: Se quiser ser completo, também tem o `INSERT INTO... SELECT`

Comment: +1 pelas formas de fazer o SQL, mas não esqueça que entrer dois bancos distintos, a chave primaria que em geral é um ID numérico dificilmente será a mesma. (No caso de se usar um UUID até é possível usar a mesma chave para o mesmo objeto entre bancos distintos). De qualquer forma, sim, tem que se definir quais valores duplicados fazem com que o registro seja considerado "duplicado", com o uso de uma chave única.

Comment: Isso.. de "geralmente ser um id numerico" é uma afirmação vaga. Se a modelagem for bem feita, a chave primária precisa realmente identificar o registro. No caso de um alarme, poderia ser um timestamp combinado com um código de usuário, por exemplo.

Answer (score -3):

SQL = """INSERT INTO tb_private (A, B, C)
SELECT  %s, %s, %s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT PRIVATE_HASH FROM tb_private WHERE C= '""" + CKEY + """')"""
val = (AKEY + ", " + BKEY + "," + CKEY)
print(SQL)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(SQL_PRIVATEKEY, val)
connection.commit()

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str (*****), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).